# sql | slow queries | avoid many joins

Tags: database, postgresql, search, architecture, relational-database

I am currently working with java spring and postgres.

I have a query on a table, many filters can be applied to the query and each filter needs many joins.
This query is very slow, due to the number of joins that must be performed, also because there are many elements in the table.
Foreign keys and indexes are correctly created.

I know one approach could be to keep duplicate information to avoid doing the joins. By this I mean creating a new table called infoSearch and keeping it updated via triggers. At the time of the query, perform search operations on said table. This way I would do just one join.
But I have some doubts:

- What is the best approach in postgres to save item list flat?
- I know there is a json datatype, could I use this to hold the information needed for the search and use jsonPath? is this performant with lists?

I also greatly appreciate any advice on another approach that can be used to fix this.
Is there any software that can be used to make this more efficient?

I'm wondering if it wouldn't be more performant to move to another style of database, like graph based. At this point the only problem I have is with this specific table, the rest of the problem is simple queries that adapt very well to relational bases.
Is there any scaling stat based on ratios and number of items which base to choose from?

Comment: All we know is that you *suspect* that joins slow down your query. Please show the table and index definitions, the query and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already analyzed the execution plan of the query. It is a table that is frequently consulted and I need a quick response, so my question at this time is about design, not query optimization.
I would like to know what alternatives exist, the query has more than 20 filters and some of those filters require more than 7 joins, from my ignorance I think it is unnecessary to add that load to postgres and wait for a quick response. I know that duplicating data can be an option, but I would like to hear other opinions, I am also interested in knowing how lists would be duplicated.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions in your question that we cannot verify, so I find it hard to give good advice.

Answer (score 1):

[Denormalization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/denormalization-in-databases/) is a tried and true way to speed up queries/reports/searching processes for relational databases.  It uses a standard time vs space tradeoff to reduce the time of query, at the cost of duplicating the data and increasing write/insert time.

There are third party tools that are specifically designed for this use-case, including search tools (like ElasticSearch, Solr, etc) and other document-centric databases.  Graph databases are probably not useful in this context.  They are focused on traversing relationships, not broad searches.